# "Attendance at" or "attendance of"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Should I use *at* or *of* in the following passage?

> and through attendance **[at/of]** the regular video conferences has
>   played an active part in ...

I guess my *attendance at school* could be questioned here, but perhaps through my  *attendance of an intensive English class* I'd be able to figure out which one to use.

Comment: Nice question - attendance has historically been associated with a specific physical location.

Comment: **AT** place, **OF/AT** event. **AT** is always true. Hope that helps mate. Have a good one.

Answer (score 6):

The use of **at** is certainly accepted with the word **attendance**. **Of** gives a connotation of possession (since it plays the role of the genitive), which isn't necessary here. So, **at** would be a better choice.